# Getting return value of null every time to Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, query-string

Receiving Null value every time to Controller. How can I solve this?

Url: http://localhost:45801/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Forder%2Fplaceorder

Code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult>Login(UserLoginVM userLoginVM,string ReturnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync
                (userLoginVM.LoginId, userLoginVM.Password, userLoginVM.RememberMe, false);

            if(result.Succeeded)
            {
                if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ReturnUrl))
                {
                    return RedirectToAction(ReturnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                   return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }    
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("","Invalid username and password");
        }
        return View(userLoginVM);
    }
```

Comment: try to add `[FromQuery]string ReturnUrl` in method parameters

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `[FromBody]` before `UserLoginVM` and `[FromQuery]` before  `string` , so your action method sign should be like this :

```
public async Task<IActionResult>Login([FromBody] UserLoginVM userLoginVM,[FromQuery] string ReturnUrl)
```

Comment: No Mustafa it is not working ,

Comment: @BOMMANAMAINA SAIRAM You could create an object including userLoginVM and ReturnUrl and put it in a parameter and then use [FromBody] attribute

Answer (score 0):

You should add `[FromQuery]` or `[FromBody]` attribute to the parameters.

Adding `[FromBody]` attribute to the parameter, force Web API to read from the request body.

Adding  `[FromQuery]` attribute to the parameter, force Web API to gets values from the query string.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult>Login([FromBody] UserLoginVM userLoginVM,[FromQuery] string ReturnUrl)
{
...
}
```